# Nginx update file if modified

Tags: javascript, css, nginx

How can I force download *.js and *.css files if they are modified?

I'm using nginx and, for now, I have this configuration for js and css files.

```
# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

This "remove" cache of every js and css file, but I want to "remove" this cache when the file has been modified.

Is it posible?

Comment: No, it is not; at least not directly in the setup you have now - because you are _telling_ the client that it doesn’t need to check for updates for the next year. The client has no way of knowing what might be modified, if you instruct it to not even _ask_. If you want to keep long-time caching, then you need to change the URLs of those resources when they get changed, in the documents that refer them. F.e. appending the last modified timestamp to the URL as a GET parameter is one simple way of achieving that.

Comment: Thx for the help, with your comment and Paul's answer I can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you could config NGINX for cache purging and then have another service (possible a node script you run) do the file watching and call the purge method for you.

NGINX config wit this in it:

map $request_method $purge_method {
    PURGE 1;
    default 0;
}

Would delete matching URLs if you make a web request to PURGE /path/to/changed/file

Comment: Thx, it is very helpfull